# Android inbuilt services like Gyroscope,Accelerator,camera etc need be accessed from another device

Tags: android

Is AIDL work for exposing the services which mentioned above remotely or there is any other technique to access this services from other device or other application

Comment: Can you give more details about the device you want to access the services from?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i have two android device, device A and device B, i need to access the inbuilt application of device A like camera etc, from device B does AIDL will be helpfull to achieve this goal or any other technique should be used.